# Notice: Undefined index: id

Tags: php

I have used a prepared statement to define the id index however, it is telling me that it is undefined for some reason, where and what do i change for this to work?

```
<?php

$db_username='student';
$db_password='student';
$db = new PDO ('mysql:host=192.168.56.2;dbname=Assessment', $db_username, $db_password);

$result = $db ->prepare("SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE jobname='".$_GET['id']."' ");
$result->execute();
```

Comment: You're using prepared statements..... and still inject user input values directly into your SQL query .... facepalm

Comment: This is what's undefined: `$_GET['id']`

Comment: The solution is to make sure that `$_GET['id']` is actually set first.... and then to use a __bind variable__ in your query

Comment: $_GET takes its parameters in your URL, make sure you have this: www.yoururl.com?id=5

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$db_username='student';
$db_password='student';
$db = new PDO ('mysql:host=192.168.56.2;dbname=Assessment', $db_username, $db_password);

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
$result = $db ->prepare("SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE jobname=?");
$result->execute(array($_GET['id']);`enter code here
}
else {echo('$_GET["id"] not set');}
```

Comment: you should use empty instead of isset, that way, if it's set and its empty it will still say it isn't set

Comment: @YannChabot  But `empty()` will result in zero being empty, no?  Or maybe not since it is a string?

Comment: You're right @user1032531 ! make it !empty, sorry for my bad. !empty will return false if variable is set and not empty, while isset will only return if the variable exists, but it won't check if it has a value

Answer (score 0):

First, verify that $_GET['id'] has a value. Second, for security, change some lines:

```
$result = $db ->prepare("SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE jobname=:id");

$result->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
```